# Using registerHelper how can I access the DOM element where this helper is used?

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I am using Template.registerHelper to register a helper that would given some boolean value will output either class1 or class2 but also some initial class if and only if it was the first time it was called for this specific DOM element.

```
Template.registerHelper('chooseClassWithInitial', function(bool, class_name1, class_name2, initial) {
    var ifFirstTime = wasICalledAlreadyForThisDOMElement?;
    return (ifFirstTime)?initial:"" + (bool)?class_name1:class_name2;
});
```

I am having a hard time figuring out how to know if the helper was called already for this specific form element.

If I could somehow get a reference to it, I could store a flag in the data attribute.

Using Template.instance() one can get to the "template" instance we are now rendering and with Template.instance().view to the Blaze.view instance, however, what if we have more than one html element inside our template ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I solved it for now was to manually provide some kind of global identifier, unique to that item, this is hardly the proper way, if anyone has suggestions let me know.

```
let chooseClassWithInitialDataStore = {};
Template.registerHelper('chooseClassWithInitial', function(bool, class_name1, class_name2, initial, id) {
    if(!chooseClassWithInitialDataStore[id]){
        chooseClassWithInitialDataStore[id] = true;
        return initial;
    }
    return (bool)?class_name1:class_name2;
});
```

To be used like:

```
<div class="ui warning message lowerLeftToast
            {{chooseClassWithInitial haveUnsavedChanges
            'animated bounceInLeft'
            'animated bounceOutLeft'
            'hidden' 'profile_changes_global_id'}}
        ">
            Unsaved changes.
</div>
```

Regarding this specific usage: I want to class it as 'animated bounceInLeft' haveUnsavedChanges is true, 'animated bounceOutLeft' when its false, and when it is first rendered, class it as 'hidden' (that is, before any changes happen, so that it doesnt even display when rendered, thus, the need for the third option, however this isnt a question about CSS, but rather about Meteor templateHelpers).

Answer (score 0):

Oh, you are doing it in the wrong direction.

If you want to manipulate the DOM, you should do it directly in the template, not the jquery way ;)

#### 0. Helper

html

```
<template name="foo">
  <div data-something="{{dataAttributeValue}}"></div>
</template>
```

js

```
Template.foo.helpers({
  dataAttributeValue: function() {
    return 'some-value';
  }
})
```

If you cannot avoid accessing the DOM from outside, then there is `Template.onRendered(callback)`, `callback` will be called only once, when the template is rendered for the first time.

---

#### 1. Component style

```
<template name="fadeInFadeOut">
 <div class="fade">{{message}}</div>
</template>
```

---

```
Template.onRendered(function() {
  // this.data is the data context you provide
  var self = this,
      ms = self.data.ms || 500;

  self.$('div').addClass('in'); // self.$('div') will only select the div in that instance!
  setTimeout(function() {
    self.$('div').removeClass('in')
    self.$('div').addClass('out')
  }, ms );
});
```

Then you can use it somewhere else:

```
<div>
  {{>fadeInFadeOut message="This message will fade out in 1000ms" ms=1000 }}   
</div>
```

So you would have a reusable Component..

Comment: My helper is agnostic to any specific template. It's made to set a class on an element like : <div class="{{chooseClassWithInitial hasDocumentChanged "fadein" "fadeout" "hidden"}} warning message">Don't forget to save!</div> so that when hasDocumentChanged is true it will put the class fadein, when not fadeout, but always start with hidden.

Comment: The hasDocumentChanged is ReactiveVar(bool) btw. And this helper is part of a big set of helpers that are not specific to any template.

Comment: @JoaoCarlos check out the Component Style, is it what you are looking for?

Comment: i think you are misunderstanding my problem. You are suggesting solutions to problems I don't actually have, thus, the solutions you are giving me won't really work.

Comment: >>the solutions you are giving me won't really work. 
have you tried?

Comment: @JoaoCarlos you can deal with some globals temp variables and dumb heplers, or create something useful with the suggestion above.. its not a copy&paste solution obviously..

Comment: If you mean they work as in "the code executes and something happens" then they might work, sure. I am not actually a beginner when it comes to programming by the way. I am not looking for a "quick fix" but more of a generic little helper that will work everywhere. Your solution 0 doesnt make much sense since its not even a helper, code-wise isnt different from what I had and does not solve the initial problem, nor does it profile any benefit to a possible solution. Your solution 1 adds a class and then removes it after 500 miliseconds, not sure what you meant to achieve there.

Comment: Regarding solution 1, if you meant to display how one could access the templates instance, I had already given away that you can use "Template.instance()" and explained why that doesnt solve the problem. Not sure if troll or ... Quick question: did you read my question to begin with?